# First chern class of vector bundle w/ push / pull

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, chern-classes

(Context: I am trying to prove the Pluecker formula.)

Let $E^{k+1}_L = \pi_{2,*}(\pi_1^*L\otimes O_{C\times C}/J_\Delta^{k+1})$, where $C$ is a smooth curve of genus $g$, $L$ a line bundle of degree $d$, $\Delta$ the diagonal in $C\times C$ and $\pi_1,\pi_2$ the projections.

I am looking to find the first Chern class of $E^{k+1}_L$ (it is supposed to be $(k+1)d+(k+1)k(g-1)$).

So far I thought of reducing this to something along these lines:

$$c_1(\pi_{2,*}((\pi_1^*L)\otimes (O/J_\Delta\oplus J_\Delta/J_\Delta^2\oplus \cdots J_\Delta^k/J_\Delta^{k+1}))$$

which looks like it might give me the factor $(k+1)$. However, I still need to figure out the other factor of $(d+k(g-1))$. I am particularly uncertain about the push-forward and pullback involved.

Any hints?

Comment: Use the Whitney sum formula to compute the first Chern class of your rank $k+1$ vector bundle as the sum of the first Chern classes of the $k+1$ line bundles $\pi_{2,*}(\pi_1^*L \otimes J_\Delta^e/J_\Delta^{e+1}$, $e=0,\dots,k$.  Next, use that the first Chern class of a tensor product of two line bundles equals the sum of the first Chern classes of the factor line bundles.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I thought about that, but was held back by the push / pull. Ignoring those we have: $c_1(E) = \pi_{2,*} (\sum_{e=0}^k c_1(\pi_1^*L \otimes J^e/J^{e+1})) = \pi_{2,*} (\sum_{e=0}^k \pi_1^* c_1(L) + c_1(J^e/J^{e+1}))$. Now that seems to suggest that $c_1(J^e/J^{e+1})$ should add up to $(k+1)k(g-1)$, but I don't know why. Also, still very uncertain about what happens with the push & pull.

Edit: afaik chern classes are functorial under pullback, but not sure what happens with the push forward.

Comment: The support of the sheaf $J^e/J^{e+1}$ equals the image of the diagonal morphism $\Delta:C\to C\times C$.  Thus, pushforward of such a sheaf via either projection is the same thing as pullback by $\Delta$.  However, based on your other comments, it sounds like you need general background on Chern classes.  Manin's "Lectures on the K functor" are excellent, as is Fulton's "Intersection Theory", etc.  The proof of the Pluecker relations is given in the exercises of Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths, Harris, "Geometry of Algebraic Curves".

Comment: @JasonStarr Thank you, and yes, I am in fact looking at Arbarello, Cornalba, Griffiths, Harris.